# Is there a way to enable logs for graph commands?

Tags: logs, docker, the-graph, subgraph, data

I am running the following version of `graph-cli`: `@graphprotocol/graph-cli/0.42.4 linux-x64 node-v18.15.0`

Is there a way to setup a log or have more details after each command gets executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to enable logs when using `graph-cli` but [this resource](https://github.com/StakeSquid/graphprotocol-mainnet-docker/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md) has helped me to achieve what I was needing.

Basically, I needed more information at the time of running commands in my The Graph `docker` container.